# How would I capture the date and time when an Excel cell is updated?

Tags: excel, vba, datatable

I have an Excel table column (K) named "Audit Status" I want to capture the date and time only once in another column (L) when the value is updated/changed to either "Performed" or "Closed" but the code I have currently in VBA seems to update the date and time every time I click the cell.

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Target
    If Cell.Column = Range("K:K").Column Then
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            Cells(Cell.Row, "L").Value = Now
        Else
            Cells(Cell.Row, "L").Value = ""
        End If
    End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: Are you using the `Worksheet_Change` event handler?

Comment: @BigBen Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) even

Comment: The `SelectionChange` event fires when the selection changes. So use `Worksheet_Change`, not `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.